# Select a specific line after matching a pattern

Tags: regex, awk

I just recently started using AWK and I'm still learning about it. I have solved the problem I'm about to show but I feel it's not the best solution and I'm trying to find a solution to fit within an AWK command rather than keep piping.

I have a bunch of .txt files ending for which I read the header (1st line only).

```
head -1 *.txt
```

Outputs:

```
==> anglia.txt <== 
String - Anglian            

==> carr.txt <==   
String - Carr               
etc..
```

From here I have a case switch where a user inputs 1-9. It's sorted so first line is always Anglian and second is always Carr.. etc
So if a user inputs 1 I know they want to select anglian. But for further process my code I need to extract the String "Anglian".

```
head -1 *.txt | awk '/[a-z]/&&!/.txt/'
```

Outputs:

```
String - Anglian
String - Carr
```

Here I got rid of the first line that had the filename.

```
head -1 *.txt | awk '/[a-z]/&&!/.txt/' | awk '{print $3}'
```

Outputs:

```
Anglian
Carr
```

Here I selected column 3 which contains the String that I need!

```
head -1 *.txt | awk '/[a-z]/&&!/.txt/' | awk 'NR==1{print $3}'
```

Outputs:

```
Anglian
```

Here I selected the first row which is exactly the output that I want! However I had to use an extra pipe. All I want is a awk command that does all of this in a single command somethings around the lines of:

```
head -1 *.txt | awk '/[a-z]/&&/.txt/{if(NR==1)print $3}'
```

Outputs:

```
EMPTY LINE
```

This is the problem I'm having. Since I'm having the pattern and NR in 1 command it's selecting the 1st line but the first line is a line that is being hidden by my pattern and it's the `==> anglian.txt <==` hence

```
head -1 *.txt | awk '/[a-z]/&&/.txt/{if(NR==2)print $3}'
```

Outputs:

```
Anglian
```

However this is of no use because only matches Anglian where it is NR==2 and due to my case switch that I have I want it to be NR==1 otherwise the code does not work.

Is this possible? I hope I made myself clear here :)

Comment: I'd like you help you, but you need more information about the files. I think that $3 on line1 is "Anglican" or one of the other keys. And that word maps to a line number, and then you want to print $3 from that line number. Is that right? Please demonstrate by including a couple of your files.

Comment: (Welcome to Code Review!) `I just recently started using AWK and I'm still learning about it` ***Why?*** It was quite something when it was new. Then, there was *new awk*, but the world keeps turning: contemporary contenders include Perl (5+), Python (3.3+, 2.7.1 for Jython), Ruby…

Comment: Please include an example of the output of `head -1 *.txt`. Without that, I can't imagine why `$3` would be printed, and I have a hard time trying to imagine [the code presented works as intended](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @greybeard I work for a company that provides the billing system to BT in the UK and we do a lot of data mediation; awk seems to be used quite often for data formatting... So i'm trying to learn it to try and understand some of the scripts we have implemented, etc although some are quite old.

Comment: So you look at the first line of a file to get a keyword. You use that keyword to get a line number. What file is that line number used for? The same file? Show your input files (or a short representation of them) and your desired output.

Comment: @greybeard awk is a very capable and fast language for processing data. It doesn't matter if it's not the shiniest tool in the box

Comment: Stop trying to *describe* the problem and just show the input. In your question where it can be properly formatted, not in comments

Comment: @glennjackman Hey, I edited the question, I hope it's more clearer now! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace this pipeline

```
head -1 *.txt | awk '/[a-z]/&&!/.txt/' | awk '{print $3}'
```

with this one awk command

```
awk 'FNR == 1 {print $3}' *.txt
```

`FNR` is the **file** record (i.e. line) number. `NR` is the *cumulative* record number of all records seen from all files.

---

Now, you can select the user's numeric choice with

```
awk 'FNR == 1 {print $3}' *.txt | awk -v n="$user_selection" 'NR == n'
```

or, with a single awk:

```
awk -v n="$user_selection" 'FNR == 1 && ++filenum == n {print $3; exit}' *.txt
```

---

If you're looking for a way to get your users to select a name from one of the files, perhaps some more advanced bash:

```
# read the 3rd word from the 1st line of all txt files into an array
readarray -t names < <(awk 'FNR == 1 {print $3}' *.txt)

# get the user to select one of them
PS3="Choose a name: "
select name in "${names[@]}"; do
    [ "$name" ] && break
done

echo "$name"
```

---

This really isn't a code review. Since you're asking "how can I do this", you should have asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: ```awk -v n="$user_selection" 'FNR == 1 && ++filenum == n {print $3; exit}' *.txt``` worked wonders :) many thanks. Also I was in stack overflow but since I had a "solution" to the problem they told me to come here. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't do this like that, because `NR` is a number of an input record, not a number of records matched so far. Even if it was, you need to count records matched by the first clause of the condition but actually *not* yet printed due to the second clause.

Probably the good way to do that is explicit counting:

```
BEGIN { cnt = N }
/[a-z]/&&!/.txt/ { if (cnt-- == 0) print  $3 }
```

I am not sure, however, how to pass an argument from the command line to the script's variable `N`.

Comment: If you do this inline instead of it's own awk script file I think you can just use Bash's variable expansion (but be sure to escape the dollar sign later in the code). Or just hard code it!